# How can I implement this locally-connected architecture in Keras?

Tags: keras

My input data looks like this:

```
> x <- rnorm(10*9, sd = 10) %>% matrix(10) %>% round
> colnames(x) <- c(paste0(2014, c("a","b", "c")), paste0(2015, c("a","b", "c")), paste0(2016, c("a","b", "c")))
> x
      2014a 2014b 2014c 2015a 2015b 2015c 2016a 2016b 2016c
 [1,]     1   -11     3     3     6     5    17     5    15
 [2,]     9     8     0    -1    10     8    -3   -11     6
 [3,]    -6    22    -3     1    -1    -4    -3    11    -9
 [4,]    10   -15     0    -2     4    14    11   -11     3
 [5,]     5     4     5     5    15    -9     2     5     1
 [6,]   -24    16     9    -7     2   -12     1    18    -2
 [7,]     1    13     5   -14     1   -10    15    -1    14
 [8,]    -8     4     4   -15    -1   -20    -6    14     5
 [9,]    10    19   -15    15    -4     3    -1   -11     8
[10,]    10   -11    -9    -1    16     3    24    -8     4
```

My outcome variable is continuous (i.e.: this is a regression problem).

I want to fit a model with an architecture that looks like this:

[image]

Basically, I've got granular data from separate years that aggregate to form a set of annual phenomena, which may themselves interact.  If I had enough data, I could just fit a bunch of fully-connected layers.  But those would be inefficient with my modest sample size.

This isn't exactly a conv net, because I don't want the "tiles" to overlap.

I also want apply both dropout and a global L2 penalty.

I'm new to Keras, but not to neural nets.  How can I implement this, and how is it referred-to in Keras terminology?

Comment: Are you using R? If you're new to keras (and to R), consider going for python, there are much more questions, answers and tutorials available. It's quite easy to implement this with Python, but I have no clue how R works.

Comment: I'm an R user, but I can understand enough python to figure out an example in that language.  AFAIK R for Keras can implement all of Keras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to have multiple inputs and create that computation graph. Something along the lines of:

```py
inputs = [Input(shape=(3,)) for _ in range(3)]
latents = list()
for i in range(3):
  latent = Dense(3, activation='relu')(inputs[i])
  latent = Dense(3, activation='relu')(latent)
  latents.append(latent)
merged = concatenate(latents)
out = Dense(4, activation='relu')(merged)
out = Dense(4, activation='relu')(out)
out = Dense(1)(out)
```

Your architecture diagram assumes you have fixed number year inputs, in this case 3 years. If you have variable number of years you have to use shared Dense layers and use [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) wrapper to apply the Dense layers to every year before merging:

```py
in = Inputs(shape=(3,3)) # this time we have 2d array of 3 years
latent = TimeDistributed(Dense(3, activation='relu'))(in) # apply same dense to every year
latent = TimeDistributed(Dense(3, activation='relu'))(latent)
merged = Flatten()(latent)
out = ...
```

This time the Dense layers are shared across years, they have the same weights essentially.

Comment: Right, a fixed number of years.  Looks like the relevant terminology is `latents`, and then there is a `concatenate` function for them.  Super-helpful, thanks.

Comment: Latent is just the intermediate hidden features, it's just a variable name in this case.

Comment: Oh right, obviously.  So then the `concatenate` function when applied to bunch of "latents" will create an architecure that keeps the "sub-nets" separate?.

Comment: Yes, I also updated a model which *shares* the dense layers for every year.